# Combining Realm and SQLite.?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, realm

Combining realm and sql-lite in a single application.

I'm trying to integrate two application of which one is in realm and another is in sqlite. Is it possible to do this

Comment: Yes, you can use both in the same application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real reason to combine a nosql and sql based database. Realm already outclassed sqlite in terms in fluent api, database queries and easy of use.To answer your question, it can be done,sqlite access are independent of realm, there is no collision because they create two separate yet unique files. A side note, maintaining two database instances on a phone can be taxing, and management will inevitably become a problem, this will also introduce security errors of course.So yea you can do it,but do not, unless your a great database administrator or something.

Comment: why would you even want to mix them,

Comment: i am trying to develop alarm in my app, which i have developed in another, in realm i'm not able to achieve this since Calendar object is not supporting in realm

Comment: what feature exactly you want.give an example

Comment: I am trying to use this function
public void setAlarmTime(Calendar alarmTime) {
        this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
    }
to set an alarm which takes Calendar as a parameter, but in realm i am not able do in the exact way.

Comment: why not get the string representation then , just parse a date object from it

Comment: i have tried it, but after parsing it to the date object and converting to the calendar milliSeconds, leading me to a bug

Comment: hmmm, what bug eactly

Comment: Alarm is not working properly, its not giving my alarm at the proper time instead its getting triggered at the time i press SET, Gregorian calendar which i'm using for which i need to pass time in milliseconds, this is causing the bug. After converting string to date, and date to gregorian.

Comment: Realm supports `Date`. I think you can use `Date date = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())` and `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(d);`